# Error in function split.default

Tags: java, r, statistics

I'm using R with SPOT and Java for calibrating parameters on an project I'm working on. The .res file looks ok, it has the values it should have. I'm new with R and SPOT and I can't find about this error anywhere. Here's the message I get:

```
  Entering spotGetRawResData
Loading result data from:: prueba.res
  Leaving spotGetRawResData
SPOT Step: 1
Create Sequential Design
  Entering spotGetRawResData
Loading result data from:: prueba.res
  Leaving spotGetRawResData
Error in split.default(rawData[, spotConfig$alg.resultColumn], rawData$CONFIG) : 
  Group length is 0 but data length > 0
```

I'm using the template .R file that comes with SPOT, here's where I think the error is ocurring:

```
res <-data.frame(res)
colNames = TRUE
if (file.exists(io.resFileName)){
   colNames = FALSE
}
## quote = false is required for JAVA
write.table(res
    , file = io.resFileName
    , row.names = FALSE
    , col.names = colNames
    , sep = " "              
    , append = !colNames
    , quote = FALSE
);      
colNames = FALSE
spotConfig$alg.currentResult=rbind(spotConfig$alg.currentResult,res);
#always log the results in spotConfig
```

Comment: I check the function `spotGetRawResData` and tried to print the value it returns. It prints `$rawD`, so I wrote `print(spotConfig$rawD);` and got `NULL`everytime. Maybe that's where the problem is, but I don't know how to check why it's getting that value.